# Smoothing aircraft GPS data with realistic turns

Tags: gps, computational-geometry, smoothing

I have historical aircraft trajectory data with points varying from 1 second - 1 minute separation. Often these points present sharp turns. I'm looking for suggestions of best methods of resampling the data to generate smooth paths (e.g. point every n seconds) that more realistically represent the path followed. It would be useful to be able to parameterize the function with certain performance characteristics (e.g. rate of change of direction).

I'm aware of algorithms like the Kalman filter, Bezier curve fitting, splines etc. for data smoothing. But what algorithms would you suggest exploring as a starting point for generating smooth turns?

Comment: Interesting problem. How do you define smooth in this context? Depending on the turn rate like degress per second?

Comment: I have information concerning the aircraft type, so its potential rate of turn and climb. I also have speed and altitude. The data has been cleaned to remove any spurious points that could be wrong. I could simply write a set of functions that model the aircraft itself. But I'm curious if there are other solutions already available for generating curves.

Comment: Why do you want to smooth them? You alwayys introduce erors with smoothing. by ethe way: Every GPS receiver has a "dynamic model " setting which allows to set aircraft mode (standard is multi purpose or automotive). So I expect if the data have been recorded with a properly set up GPS device, there should not need for any further smootihng.

Comment: Further you shoudl add the comment of the deleted answer in your question: "You want to (smooth) interpolate", not smooth. Further I expect that the "sharp" turns (proably corners" are a result of linear interpolation. These sharp turns are not contained in the original data. (you probably dont see a sharp turn consiting of 20 positions with each 1s intervall). i expcect, The sharp tunrs are a resulöt of linera imnterpolation of 1minute samples.

Comment: The data is from commercial aviation. Often it is reduced in complexity and detail for all kinds of reasons, or it may be captured by other (passive) systems. Reason for resampling is post processing various proximity events. I'm entirely fine with the fact its an approximation of the possible aircraft path, not a factual position.

Comment: For your application be sure to choose an interpolation which resulting path goes through your positions. Many, like B-Spline interpolation do not go through the points.

Comment: check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline. IIRC for cubic you'll need to set tangent angles at chords joint points; either use a (flipped) bisector (i.e. average of the two chords' angles) or tilt it in reverse proportion to the adjacent chord lengths ratio (so the tangent is closer to the shorter chord).

Answer (score 3):

*[Schneider's Algorithm](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=90941)* is an algorithm that approximately fits curves through a series of points.

The resulting curves have a drastically reduced point-count and it's error-tolerance is *configurable*, so you can adjust it as much as you need to.

In general:

- **Lower error-tolerance:** More points, more accurate, less execution
- **Higher error-tolerance:** Less points, less accurate, faster execution

Some useful links:

- A [live Javascript example](http://soswow.github.io/fit-curve/demo/), and it's [implementation here](https://github.com/soswow/fit-curve).
- [Python Example](https://github.com/volkerp/fitCurves)
- [C++ implementation](https://github.com/vicrucann/CurveFitting)

If the resulting curve *must* pass exactly through your points, you need an *interpolation* algorithm instead of an *approximation* algorithm, but keep in mind that those do not reduce point-count.

A really good type of interpolating spline is the [Centripetal Catmull-Rom Spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_Catmull%E2%80%93Rom_spline).